# gcc compile error: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()'

Tags: c++, gcc

I got this compile error:

```
in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
/usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:116: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()'
```

This is GCC 10.

Following this https://openmc.discourse.group/t/undefined-reference-to-throw-bad-array-new-length/3189, I do have throw_bad_array_new_length defined in libstdc++.so

```
objdump -T /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/libstdc++.so |c++filt|grep throw_bad_array_new_length
00000000000a41d3 g    DF .text  0000000000000035  GLIBCXX_3.4.29 std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()
00000000000a14ae g    DF .text  0000000000000035  CXXABI_1.3.8 __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you compile? Did you do `gcc your_program.cpp -o something`?

Comment: g++ your_program.cpp -o something

Comment: Ok, that's odd. If you do `g++ --version` and then `true|g++ -E -Wp,-v -` what does those commands print? `gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11` doesn't seem to match gcc 10. I'd expect `10` instead of `11` for gcc 10. How many gcc installations do you have?

Comment: If you write something here and leave it for 18 hours without responding to comments, your question will likely get closed. It's very rare that questions of this kind are so complete that there are no follow-up questions - and you need to be present to be able to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in one of the -L linker path (a very long list), there is an older version of libstdc++.so. Remove that linker path or the libstdc++.so in the linker path works.